# Provisioning Profile Expiry iOS

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Does anybody have a good solid answer as to what happens when a provisioning profile expires for iOS? Does it just prevent you making any updated without generating a new profile or does anything else happen?

Our app has just expired however it still seems to be available on the app store etc.

Thanks!

Comment: A provisioning profile has nothing to do with the app on the app store. Its you being allowed to install your app on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

A distribution profile expiring has absolutely no effect on an app already on the iTunes store. It simply means you will not be able to submit another version of that app until renewed.

An expired development profile will stop you installing the app on actual devices. In addition an installed app with an expired development profile will crash when launched.